# Get specific value of node by attribute value

Tags: java, xml

```
<row id="1">
 <column name="Date">30.01.2029 00:00:00 +02:00</column>
 <column name="Jackpot ID">sol_3430_32488</column>
 <column name="Jackpot Name">Level1</column>
 <column name="Jackpot Value">0</column>
 <column name="Casino Seed">87.5</column>
 <column name="Currency">USD</column>
</row>
```

I wrote this code which get it, and I think calling with index is not good idea, sometimes xml doesnt contains currency and it fails

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    f.setNamespaceAware(false);
    f.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    Document doc = b.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");


    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(itr);


        ArrayList<String> tabInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        if (node.getNodeType() ==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) node;

            String data = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(0).getTextContent();
            String jpId = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(1).getTextContent();
            String jpValue = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(2).getTextContent();
            String casinoName = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(3).getTextContent();
            String casinoSeed = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(4).getTextContent();
            String casinoCurrency = eElement.getElementsByTagName("column").item(5).getTextContent();
```

is there a way to interact by attributes? if there is Data,jackpot,etc. return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath as follows to read elements by an attribute value:

```
    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expressionJackpotID = "//column[@name='Jackpot ID']/text()";
    String expressionJackpotName = "//column[@name='Jackpot Name']/text()";
    // etc
    String expressionCurrency = "//column[@name='Currency']/text()";

    XPathExpression compiledExpressionJackpotID = xPath.compile(expressionJackpotID);
    XPathExpression compiledExpressionJackpotName = xPath.compile(expressionJackpotName);
    //etc
    XPathExpression compiledExpressionCurrency = xPath.compile(expressionCurrency);

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");


    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(itr);

        List<String> tabInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String jackpotId = (String) compiledExpressionJackpotID.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
            String jackpotName = (String) compiledExpressionJackpotName.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
            // etc
            String currency = (String) compiledExpressionCurrency.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you to change the question title to "Get specific value of node by attribute value"